# Sellotape caused discoloration on the wooden surface

Tags: repair, wood, damage

As seen in the picture it seems that the sellotape removed some of the color on the furniture surface. There doesn't seem to be any adhesive left on the surface. What are my options to repair this? [image] 
Wood

Comment: Looks like they used a tinted varnish rather than staining the wood. You could try layering on very thin coats of another tinted varish, feathering the edges and progressively working toward an approximate mstch..

Comment: would sth like restor a finish help with this?

Answer (score 1):

hard to tell from the photo, but I think you have old varnish, just aged and oxidized.  take some acetone and wipe the area at the edge of the ripped area.  if you wipe it and get some yellowy residue, you probably have old varnish or lacquer.  if not, wipe with methanol or methyl hydrate.  if this produces yellowy residue, you have old shellac.  if it doesn't wipe with either process you may have a urethane that's tinted and it would need sanding and refinishing.

either way, if it wipes off with either chemical, just wet feather the edge and then let dry.  you should see a lighter area when it dries, but with a smooth transition.  then you can topcoat.  don't try to match colours as the area will naturally darken in the stripped wood section when you coat it, and then further as it ages.

Answer (score 0):

I have had great luck with [this product](http://www.oldenglishpolish.com/sf2_all.shtml). I usually do not advocate specific brands but I know of no other product like this. It just wipes on, it's like an oil polish which *blends* away imperfections and discoloration. You should apply it to the whole area, but you will not notice that color change afterwards. They make it for dark wood or med./light wood, your's looks like med./light.

[image]